# How to use Avatar object in card mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I use an Avatar object in a Card mui? Currently my code snippet is as follows:

```
mycard = () => (
<Card>
    <CardHeader
        title="RamPriya"
        avatar="https://scontent.fmaa3-1......"
    />
</Card>
)
```

And it works, but

> I would like to use a Avatar **object** instead of specifying the 'avatar' in myCard to the image. I would rather want to **set** the image source in the Avatar object and point the Avatar object to 'avatar'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `.png` or `.jpg` you want to use to a folder of your project and them import it as

```
import avatar from '<path_to_image_assset>';
```

And use is inside a render as

```
<CardHeader
    title="RamPriya"
    avatar={avatar}
/>
```

Comment: I would like to use Avatar attributes like size, style etc.. along with src.  So was looking at something like:
    myAvatar = () => (
    <Avatar>
        src=...
        size=...
        style=..
    </Avatar>
    )

and use the above in a Card, but not sure how.